# Wrap only the first div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I wrapped a class but i only want to wrap the first div.class productInfo and not  the second how's that possible?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("div.productInfo").wrap("<div id='productDetails' />");
});
</script>
```

and here's the HTML

```
<div class="productInfo">the first div.
</div>
<div class="productInfo">the secondn div
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/ or http://api.jquery.com/first/

I imagine `$("div.productInfo:first")` or `$("div.productInfo").first()` will work.

Comment: It's also worth noting that when you run into problems like this in future, googling jquery, selectors, and what you're trying to select (in this case you are after the first element of a returned set, or just first) will yield what you're after.